# Is it possible to force a browser to do htm5 video decoding by software only? That is, disable hardware acceleration

Tags: javascript, html, macos, video, hardware-acceleration

I built a html5 video player, but I found issues with inaccurate time seeking, specifically on OS X & when hardware acceleration is enabled for frame decoding. Try it yourself - go to any page with a video ( ex: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp ) and run these in the console-

```
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var vidPlay = setInterval(function(){ vid.currentTime+=(1/30) }, 250);
```

You'll see the video pseudo-playing, but if you watch you'll occasionally see incorrect frames. Using a different frame rate doesn't help (that's the 1/30 part). Here is a video of what I'm seeing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I561KHt2af4

Is there a way to overcome this issue, aside from asking the user to disable hardware acceleration in their browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this library on github:
[VideoFrame](https://github.com/X3TechnologyGroup/VideoFrame)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Zq/184/) with it implemented

```
// Just posting this here so I can add a fiddle link.
// Check the link
var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
var video = VideoFrame({
    id : 'video',
    frameRate: 29.97,
    callback : function(frame) {
        currentFrame.html(frame);
    }
});

$('#play-pause').click(function(){
    if(video.video.paused){
        video.video.play();
        video.listen('frame');
        $(this).html('Pause');
    }else{
        video.video.pause();
        video.stopListen();
        $(this).html('Play');
    }
});
```

Comment: That library looks to be using the exact same method, i.e. video.currentTime



https://github.com/X3TechnologyGroup/VideoFrame/blob/master/VideoFrame.js for source

Comment: I had problems with video seeking before so thought this may help you, I do not have an IOS device so can not see the problem you are having. You might want to say what you specifically mean by "inaccurate time seeking" for those of us who don't see the issue.

Comment: Sure, here is a video of what I'm seeing. You'll see it advancing through like it's playing but I'm just adding 1/30 of a second on a set interval. Occasionally you'll see it miss the correct location, resulting in the wrong frame being displayed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I561KHt2af4

Comment: hmm, I see, Maybe try pausing the video before setting the time.

Comment: the problem happens regardless of whether it's playing or paused. in fact, if you look closely, the first thing i did in that youtube link was video.pause()